# Class with stringstream trying to pass by value?

Tags: c++, std, stringstream

I have a class with a stringstream:

```
class NetMessageEncoder
{
    std::stringstream m_ss;
    std::stringstream m_numSS;
public:
    NetMessageEncoder();
    void beginMessage();
```

...

I then have another class with an instance of this class in it that I'm trying to make a vector of:

```
m_games.resize(100);
```

This line produces:

```
Error   1   error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'    c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\sstream 516
```

I gather that it might be because the vector needs to copy the class with I guess causes the stringstream to copy by value or something?

The stringstream is indeed the cause, compiles fine if removed.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

```
    struct TableS
    {
        ServerPlayer* m_players[4];
        SpadesGameInfo m_info;
        NetSpadesGame m_game;
        bool readyToPlay() const
        {
            int count = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
            {
                if(m_players[i])
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            return count >= m_info.getNumPlayers();
        }
        TableS()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
            {
                m_players[i] = NULL;
            }
        }
    };
    class ServerCore : public ServerHost, public NetEventListener
    {
        NetEventDecoder m_dec;
        NetEventEncoder m_enc;
        std::vector<ServerPlayer*> m_players;
        int m_totalPlayers;
        std::vector<TableS> m_games;
    public:
...
```

Comment: what is the definition of `m_games`?

Comment: but where do you use `NetMessageEncoder`? It does not appear in your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiler returns "synthesized method ‘operator=’ first required here"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305407/compiler-returns-synthesized-method-operator-first-required-here)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ copy a stream object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903903/c-copy-a-stream-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of the followings:

1) Override copy constructor and assignment operator of `NetMessageEncoder` and deal with stream copying yourself (using a new stream for the copy could be enough in your case, I guess)

2) Avoid copying of streams by using `std::vector<TableS*> m_games;` instead of `std::vector<TableS> m_games;`

Answer (score 4):

Streams are *non-copyable*, and so its your `NetMessageEncoder` since it contains streams as members. If you are using **C++11** you can overcome this limitation by making your type *moveable*.